# Apple Mach-O Linker Error/Boost Wave Compilation Issues

Tags: xcode, boost

I'm trying to compile a simple Boost Wave example and while Xcode is recognizing the headers, it is giving me a slew of Apple Mach-O Linker(Id) Errors. I have encountered this before and I don't remember how I solved it. Please help!

I have attached a screenshot.

P.S. I have Boost 1.57.0 and it works just fine with any Xcode Project. For whatever reason, though, it isn't in the case when it involves the header boost/wave.hpp like so...

```
#include <boost/wave.hpp>
```

Also, I ruled out the body of the code as a culprit. This throws the linker erros:

```
#include <boost/wave.hpp>
int main() { return 0; }
```

Other Boost headers like these, do not:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
int main() { return 0; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, but have no idea why this is the case. If anyone would like to add an explanation, that would be splendid. I had to manually add the various dynamic and static libraries referenced in each of the above issues. I attached a new screenshot so others having this issue can see the end result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This saves my day!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the explanation is very simple. In order to be able to build your project, the compiler working under the hood needs to know:

1. Where to search for the **#include <..>** within your project's files: this corresponds to the **-I** directory option for the g++ compiler.  In Xcode this corresponds to set the "**Header Search Paths**" in the Build Settings of you project. 
   Without specifying the **Header Search Paths**, you will get errors on the **#include** lines since Xcode doesn't know where to look for those included files.
2. Where to search for the library that must be linked to your source code while building the project: this corresponds to the **-L** directory option for the g++ compiler.  In Xcode this corresponds to set the "**Library Search Paths**" in the Build Settings of you project.
   Without specifying the ** Library Search Paths**, you will get errors while trying to build your project since Xcode doesn't know where to look for the linked libraries.
3. What libraries must be linked to your project files at compilation time: this corresponds to the **-l** linking option for the g++ compiler.
   In Xcode this corresponds to add the **.dylib** files to the **Link Binary With Libraries** in the Build Phases settings of your project. Note that you don't need to add manually the libraries to the main folder of your project, the last described step suffice.

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC17) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC16) for the directory and linking options of the g++ compiler, respectively.